# Enable bluetooth tethering via command line

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, bluetooth, tethering, command-line

Is there a way to activate the bluetooth tethering mode in Lollipop using the command line? You can do it for usb tethering by running the command
service call connectivity 30 i32 1
Is there a similar way for bluetooth tethering? (my problem is that it turns off at each reboot)

Thank you!